# How to try catch block in Jmeter.Webdriver webdriver Sampler

Tags: webdriver, jmeter

I want to do the exception handling in Jmeter.Webdriver Webdriver Sampler

Please let me , How to use try/catch block in Jmeter.Webdriver webdriver Sampler ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via normal JavaScript [try block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch), here is an example of taking a screenshot when error occurs:

```
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium)
var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait)
var conditions = org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions
var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5)
var exception = null

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()


try {
    WDS.browser.get('http://example.com')
    wait.until(conditions.presenceOfElementLocated(pkg.By.linkText('Not existing link')))
} catch (err) {
    WDS.log.error(err.message)
    var screenshot = WDS.browser.getScreenshotAs(pkg.OutputType.FILE)
    screenshot.renameTo(java.io.File('screenshot.png'))
    exception = err
} finally {
    throw (exception)
}

WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd())
```

Don't forget to "throw" the error after you handle it otherwise it will be "swallowed" and you get a false positive result.

See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](http://The%20WebDriver%20Sampler:%20Your%20Top%2010%20Questions%20Answered) article for more tips and tricks

Comment: It would be better if we check the exception object ( exception!= null ) before throwing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Surround the code with `try block` and add `catch block` at the end by giving `variable name` to capture the exception. (in the example, it is `exc`)

try as follows:

```
try{   
    WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
    WDS.browser.get('http://jmeter-plugins.org')
    var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium)
    WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('what')) // there is no such element with id what
    WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
}
catch(exc){ //exc variable name
    WDS.log.error("element not found" + exc)
}
```

in the `JMeter log`, you can see the complete trace of `NoSuchElementException`, which is raised when trying to find the element by id with the values as `what`, which is not present in the HTML.

Note: use `View Results in Table` to see the `Sampler response time`.

Reference:

1. https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/

Reference Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is same as how do you do in other IDEs like eclipse.
you can see below code

```
//try block starts here
 try{  
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("element"))).click();
   }
  catch(Exception e)
     {
        WDS.log.info("Exception is : " +e);//you can print the exception in jmeter log.
    }
```

double quotes should be replaced with the single quote if you are using javascript Since the BeanShell is easy and it is similar to java use BeanShell as much as possible